# Java android convert image to byte [] without compress and convert byte[] to img

Tags: java, android, arrays, nullpointerexception, android-bitmap

Hi I want to convert a Bitmap to byte[] i did this :

```
byte[] imageInByte;
Uri uri = data.getData();
bitmap = null;
try {
    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}    
int size = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
imageInByte = byteBuffer.array();
```

Next I want to convert this byte[] to Bitmap and I did this :

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageInByte, 0, imageInByte.length);
```

And when I what check a `bmp.getWidth();` 
and show in Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(this,bmp.getWidth()+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I have nullpointer please help me

Comment: @Community Wrong marking. The question was how to prevent a null bitmap. Not what a NullPointerException was. Please undo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reverse of `copyPixelsToBuffer()` is not `decodeByteArray()` but `copyPixelsFromBuffer()`.